# Is there a way to see how many times a track has been shared SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Ive been digging into the public API and also the private API -  `https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/users/29120620/likes?limit=1&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1`
and its starting to seem like that is not a piece of information that SC keeps track of, but it just doesn't makes sense to me so I was just wondering if anyone knows where to find this information.

Answer (score 0):

No the SoundCloud API does not provide a share count.